# How to insert /FAILIFMISMATCH:"_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0" in .lib file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am trying to understand various aspects of _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010.

To that end, I created a DLL from a very simple .cc file:

```
#include <vector>

__declspec(dllexport) void foo(std::vector<int>& a);

#ifndef _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL
#error _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL is not defined
#endif

void foo(std::vector<int>& a)
{
   a.push_back(10);
}
```

I created the object file using the flag `/MD` (Runtime Library = Multi-threaded DLL). The object file has the token `/FAILIFMISMATCH:"_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0"` in it. However, the corresponding .lib file does not have any such thing. That creates a problem when the DLL is used by an executable whose .cc file has been compiled with `/MDd` (Runtime Library = Multi-threaded Debug DLL). There are no errors at link time but program crashes at run time.

From what I understand, after reading various articles on the net, if the .lib created by the above VS Project contains the above token, the creation of the EXE will fail at link time, preventing run time problems.

What do I need to change in the VS Project of the DLL to make sure that the above token is inserted in the .lib file?

Comment: No can do.  These directives are inserted by `#pragma detect_mismatch` and end up in the .drectve section of a .obj or .lib file.  The import .lib file for a DLL is however special, you can't get the linker to pay attention to anything else in the .lib but the exported functions.  Not even if you force the .drectve section to be inserted (I tried).  Matching what happens in Real Life as well, the actual DLL that will be found at runtime can't promise the right iterator debugging level either.

Comment: @HansPassant, That's strange. I have some third party libraries that appear to contain the exported functions but also contain the iterator debugging level directives. Maybe I am mistaken about the contents of those .lib files. Time to dig deeper.